# Remove all except some DOM elements in java?

Tags: java, dom, xpath

I want to change my DOM tree by removing all nodes except some. 
For example, if I want my new DOM to have one of the leaf nodes of the old one, everything needs to be deleted expect the leaf and everyone of his parents (ancestors). Basically I have a list of nodes at some depth that need to be saved and everything else removed.

Iterating on every level to remove nodes takes to much time. I also tried approaching this using "ancestor-or-self" with xpath but that's not helping me delete nodes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Some notes, but do read the link: Give an example of the HTML structure you're modifying, an example of what result you want, say which DOM library you're using, and show your code that won't let you delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT is designed for this job; it can be called from Java, and it can operate on DOM trees. Basically the rules you outline in your question translate directly into template rules in XSLT, but to give you examples I would need a more precise specification.